# Auto resizing css

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm making a component and am trying to achieve the following ( ideally using flexbox ) without using javascript. Think of it as a messenger chat screen with a header and a footer with controls.

[image]

Rules:

- The size of the pink container could be anything, it does 100% width/height on its parent with a minimum of 200px
- The height of 1 & 3 are also dynamic ( could be 100px , could be 300 depending on text)
- The content in 2 must be scrollable and with a min-height:200px

The main issue im facing is that i want 1,2 and 3 to not overflow the pink container.
Any ideas? Kinda stumped with this one and not sure if it is the case that im missing some constraints without which the problem is ill described.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I don't think providing code will generate a better question. What I don't understand, is if 1 & 2 heights are based off the content, and the middle one's min width is always 200, how can it overflow the pink box when it does 100% height of the parent. I could see it being an issue if it was a fixed height. Unless you mean if the height of pink box is less than the min width of #2, say like 150px. You can't request something to explicitly maintain a height, only to want it to go down later magically. You add media queries to change min height in that circumstance, or set `overflow` to hidden

Comment: I didn't mean min-width above, sloppy on my part, but you know what I meant I hope. Additionally, if you want something to be a min-height and scrollable, at what point does it start being scrollable?

Comment: good question. assume that the pink box is always bigger than 200px just to make things a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this fits your idea, the key thing is the flex property of the content div.

I've let the header and footer with the default values: 1 0 auto and set the content to 200px as initial height (is height because the flex container direction is set to column), but it allow the div to grow more than these 200px.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header, .footer {
  background: green;
}
.footer {
  justify-self: flex-end;  
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
<div class="header">
For one beautiful night I knew what it was like to be a grandmother. Subjugated, yet honored. I'm a thing. Say what? No, of course not. It was… uh… porno. Yeah, that's it. Hey! I'm a porno-dealing monster, what do I care what you think?  </div>
  <div class="content">
Wow! A superpowers drug you can just rub onto your skin? You'd think it would be something you'd have to freebase. Also Zoidberg. Oh sure! Blame the wizards! It must be wonderful. No! The kind with looting and maybe starting a few fires!

    I suppose I could part with 'one' and still be feared…
    What are their names?
    Wow, you got that off the Internet? In my day, the Internet was only used to download pornography.

Ok, we'll go deliver this crate like professionals, and then we'll go ride the bumper cars. Yes, I saw. You were doing well, until everyone died. Oh, how awful. Did he at least die painlessly? …To shreds, you say. Well, how is his wife holding up? …To shreds, you say.

Fry, we have a crate to deliver. Does anybody else feel jealous and aroused and worried? You'll have all the Slurm you can drink when you're partying with Slurms McKenzie! It's okay, Bender. I like cooking too.

Who said that? SURE you can die! You want to die?! You won't have time for sleeping, soldier, not with all the bed making you'll be doing. Do a flip! As an interesting side note, as a head without a body, I envy the dead.

Who's brave enough to fly into something we all keep calling a death sphere? Goodbye, cruel world. Goodbye, cruel lamp. Goodbye, cruel velvet drapes, lined with what would appear to be some sort of cruel muslin and the cute little pom-pom curtain pull cords. Cruel though they may be…

I didn't ask for a completely reasonable excuse! I asked you to get busy! Stop! Don't shoot fire stick in space canoe! Cause explosive decompression! You won't have time for sleeping, soldier, not with all the bed making you'll be doing.

It's just like the story of the grasshopper and the octopus. All year long, the grasshopper kept burying acorns for winter, while the octopus mooched off his girlfriend and watched TV. But then the winter came, and the grasshopper died, and the octopus ate all his acorns. Also he got a race car. Is any of this getting through to you? A true inspiration for the children.

Yes! In your face, Gandhi! WINDMILLS DO NOT WORK THAT WAY! GOOD NIGHT! I was having the most wonderful dream. Except you were there, and you were there, and you were there! Isn't it true that you have been paid for your testimony?

Whoa a real live robot; or is that some kind of cheesy New Year's costume? When the lights go out, it's nobody's business what goes on between two consenting adults. Fry, you can't just sit here in the dark listening to classical music.

There's one way and only one way to determine if an animal is intelligent. Dissect its brain! And why did 'I' have to take a cab? And remember, don't do anything that affects anything, unless it turns out you were supposed to, in which case, for the love of God, don't not do it!

We'll go deliver this crate like professionals, and then we'll go home. And from now on you're all named Bender Jr. Is that a cooking show? You're going back for the Countess, aren't you? Noooooo!

Look, everyone wants to be like Germany, but do we really have the pure strength of 'will'? Oh, I always feared he might run off like this. Why, why, why didn't I break his legs? Why am I sticky and naked? Did I miss something fun?  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    lorem asdasd
  </div>
</div>
```